# Java - retrieving inherited items from HashMap

Tags: inheritance, hashmap, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass - Vehicle which has two subclasses - Bicycle and Car

I am passing car or bicycle as an object into a hashmap.

When I try to retrieve the object Vehicle from the hashmap, the data is there but when displayed it is null

here is a screenshot to understand better - http://i.imgur.com/7b4LCvC.png

This is my code, I am getting a Vehicle Object from the 'vehicleHashMap' however, when printed out, the items are null.

```
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
    v1.retrieveVehicleFromList(GlobalVariables.vehicleHashMap, vehicleIDToSearch);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Vehicle ID - "+v1.getVehicleID());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Type - "+v1.getVehicleType());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Brand - "+v1.getVehicleBrand());
    System.out.println("Vehicle Model - "+v1.getVehicleModel());       
    System.out.println("Vehicle Cost - "+v1.getVehicleCost());
```

Do I need to cast the vehicle to CAR or BICYCLE ?

Comment: Ok found the error, it was a stupid error.. as always

v1 = v1.retrieveVehicleFromList(GlobalVariables.vehicleHashMap, vehicleIDToSearch);

V1 =     was missing

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the error, it was a stupid error.. as always

**v1 =** v1.retrieveVehicleFromList(GlobalVariables.vehicleHashMap, vehicleIDToSearch)